# AS3 TweenLite Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween, gsap, fla

I'm using tweenlite to move several objects around in my flash, however I have a weird issue that seems to only affect Firefox. Chrome/IE play the swf no problem.

In my fla, I have a function that executes around 10 different tweens, some of them with onComplete callbacks to execute other tweens and change some variables. It seems in firefox only those tweens with callbacks are not getting executed. I was considering using timelinelite however a lot of variables get changed/set so I'm not sure if the timeline class can do that.

Below is a bit of sample code, none of the ExternalInterface.call("debug","x"); commands inside the onComplete callbacks execute in firefox. In chrome/ie it does.

If someone can take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it!

```
function expandPanel():void {
            // I've removed a lot of code, but again none of the debug queries are executed in firefox
    ExternalInterface.call("debug","1");
    Content_2.MainImage.alpha = 0;
    Content_2.Text_Title.alpha = 0;
    ExternalInterface.call("debug","2");
    Content_2.visible=true;
    tmpTimer.stop();
    Controller.y = -140;
    ExternalInterface.call("debug","3");
    TweenLite.to(HoverBG, .5, {delay:0, y:-70, alpha:0, onComplete:function():void{
        ExternalInterface.call("debug","4");
        // some code here
    }});
    Content_2.Text_1.x = 940;
    Content_2.Text_2.x = 940;
    ExternalInterface.call("debug","5");
    TweenLite.to(Content_2.MainImage, 1, {delay:0, alpha:1});
    TweenLite.to(Content_2.Text_Title, 1, {delay:0, alpha:1});
    ExternalInterface.call("debug","6");
    TweenLite.to(Content_2, .5, {delay:0, alpha:1, y:0, onComplete:function():void{
        ExternalInterface.call("debug","7");
        TweenLite.to(Content_2.Text_1, 1, {delay:.3, x:310, ease:Back.easeOut});
        TweenLite.to(Content_2.Text_2, 1, {delay:.6, x:310, ease:Back.easeOut});
        ExternalInterface.call("debug","8");
    }});
    ExternalInterface.call("debug","9");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if this is just a problem with the ExternalInterface calls in Firefox, perhaps replace those with trace() statements.  I'm a bit surprised that IE and chrome are sharing behavior, usually it's a difference in the ActiveX plugin vs the NS plugin if anything, or the Object parameters versus the Embed parameters, but generally that means chrome and firefox share behavior.  Because of that I wonder if the javascript is failing in firefox but being run correctly in IE and Chrome, trace statements in place of ExternalInterface would eliminate or point out this possibility.